# Multiple Join on the same table-Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]

I tried the below query

```
SELECT Customer.*,
       ElectrnicItem.Product1 AS ElectronicItem1,
       ElectrnicItem.Product2 AS ElectronicItem2,
       ElectrnicItem.Product3 AS ElectronicItem3,
       ApparelItem.Product1 AS ApparelItem1,
       ApparelItem.Product2 AS ApparelItem2,
       ApparelItem.Product3 AS ApparelItem3
FROM Customer
LEFT JOIN Inventory AS ElectrnicItem 
ON (Customer.CustomerID = ElectrnicItem.CustomerID)
LEFT JOIN Inventory AS ApparelItem 
ON (Customer.CustomerID = ApparelItem.CustomerID)
```

but it always returns:

> ORA-00918 column ambiguously defined

Comment: Can you break down Customer.* to Customer.CustomerID, Customer.CustomerName? Not sure if that's the problem.

Comment: what is the name of the columns in your Customer table?

Comment: Can you replace the image with `CREATE TABLE` statements? It's normally better to post real code (text we can copy and paste to test ourselves) than pictures of code.

Comment: Is normalising the data an option?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing any predicate to identify rows in Inventory as either 'Electronic' or 'Apparel' for one thing. Not sure that's the fix though.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT a.customer_id, a.customer_name, b.product1 electronicitem1,
       b.product2 electronicitem2, b.product3 electronicitem3,
       c.product1 apparelitem1, c.product2 apparelitem2,
       c.product3 apparelitem3
 FROM customer a, inventory b, inventory c
WHERE a.customer_id = b.customer_id(+)
  AND b.product_type(+) = 'Electronic'
  AND a.customer_id = c.customer_id(+)
  AND c.product_type(+) = 'Apparel';
```

Answer (score 0):

I created tables Customer and Inventory, also inserted the values that you have provided. The following is the query :

```
select customer.*,ElectrnicItem.Product1 as ElectronicItem1,
ElectrnicItem.Product2  as ElectronicItem2,
ElectrnicItem.Product3 as ElectronicItem3,
ApparelItem.Product1 as ApparelItem1,
ApparelItem.Product2 as ApparelItem2,
ApparelItem.Product3 as ApparelItem3 
from customer 
left join inventory as ElectrnicItem on 
(customer.CustomerID = ElectrnicItem.CustomerID ) 
left join inventory as ApparelItem 
on (customer.CustomerID = ApparelItem.CustomerID )
```

It works fine and gives the following result:

```
    1   David Miller    mobile  headphone   trimmer mobile  headphone   trimmer
    2   Johnson         jeans   tshirt      NULL   jeans    tshirt      NULL               
    3   Diggs           NULL    NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL        NULL
```

The expected output that you have mentioned will never be achieved. Because `Customer` table contains `CustomerId` and `CustomerName`, `Customer.*` will retrieve both `CustomerId` and `CustomerName`. So `CustomerName` column can not contain any `NULL`
values.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a bit late, but...
You don´t use AS to alias a table in Oracle, only to alias a column. Try to drop all those AS from the tables aliases:

```
SELECT Customer.*,
       ElectrnicItem.Product1 AS ElectronicItem1,
       ElectrnicItem.Product2 AS ElectronicItem2,
       ElectrnicItem.Product3 AS ElectronicItem3,
       ApparelItem.Product1 AS ApparelItem1,
       ApparelItem.Product2 AS ApparelItem2,
       ApparelItem.Product3 AS ApparelItem3
FROM Customer
LEFT JOIN Inventory ElectrnicItem 
ON (Customer.CustomerID = ElectrnicItem.CustomerID)
LEFT JOIN Inventory ApparelItem 
ON (Customer.CustomerID = ApparelItem.CustomerID)
```